# Not able import spark SQL in Maven

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to import Spark SQL. I am not able to import. I am not sure about the mistake what I am making. I am just a starting learner.

```
package MySource
import java.sql.{DriverManager, ResultSet}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.util.Properties

object MyCalc {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    println("This is my first Spark")

    //val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("SparkSQL")
      //.master("YARN")
      .master("local[*]")
      //.enableHiveSupport()
      //.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","file:///c:/temp")
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
    }
}
```

> Error:(3, 8) object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
>       import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
>       Error:(15, 17) not found: value SparkSession
>           val spark = SparkSession

Comment: Can you share your pom file?

Comment: <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: here are the dependencies i have in POM

Comment: So there is one detail there. You are using the `spark-core` with scala version 2.10 and your `spark-sql` with scala version 2.11.